# Why are some(?) subjective questions (mostly) by popular users allowed? Are other users second-class?

Tags: discussion, support

I felt like being treated as a second-class user on SO when I saw [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3979679/399268), which was more about history of a programming language than anything else, being closed as subjective. And I see questions like

> [What's the hardest or most
>   misunderstood aspect of LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/215548/399268)

by popular users **not** being classified as subjective. (There are other examples too.)

Yes, I'm aware it asked for what *you* find most difficult in the body of the question. Call it a poll. But then all subjective questions can be converted to polls by forming then to ask for only *your* opinion.

My question asked only for historical reasons for why something was created. I don't know how that is subjective (people may differ on why *they* think it was so) but the recorded history is only fact.

My question was

> [Why did C# come to be when we already
>   had Java? (History)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3979679/399268)

but I doubt it that even if I had framed it as

> Why do *you* think C# came to be when
>   we already had Java?

it wouldn't have been closed.

Do some users just have special treatment?

**PS:** If you say Jon Skeet's question was for a talk he was going to deliver then I don't see how my question couldn't have been for a book I am writing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a few points:

- Don't forget to look at the date of Jon Skeet's question: June 27, 09. The view on what is "subjective and argumentative" has changed over time, becoming stricter.
- `Do some users just have special treatment?` I'd say clearly "yes" in that people will think twice before voting to close a question from a high-reputation user; but "no" in that eventually, it will get closed like any other question, without exception.
- Don't forget it takes only five people to vote to close.
- Also, you got a nice amount of feedback, didn't you?

You could consider asking the question with an alternative wording - say, "What technological factors and necessities led to the development of C#? Were some of the key points not already covered by Java?" or something like that. The same question can often pass through when worded differently.

Comment: I still don't seem to get how my question should have been closed.

Comment: @Ashish well, in my view, it fulfills "subjective and argumentative", altough it is a good question. I added a paragraph with a re-wording suggestion - no guarantees that'll work better, but it might

Comment: Re-wording suggestion?

Comment: @Ashish the last paragraph

Comment: I've credited you with the re-wording. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

No you are not a second-class user. The problem you are facing is that the community has changed a lot.

In the beginning SO was new and the community needed to grow and adapt. Lots of serious questions has been asked and answered, but several not so serious got lots of attention.

There were open/close wars and countless debates and finally the community is more or less settled to the serious question part. So all questions that do not fit in this category have a chance to be closed.

Keep in mind, that to close a question, you need the vote of five users with 3000 rep. (In the beginning one user would be enough.) And it also takes the same amount of votes to reopen the question.

Your question is in the grey area. But now it needs 2 additional reopen votes.

Comment: Thank you. I've even reworded it. And I'm new here do I had no idea about how *things have changed*.

Comment: @Ashish:  Much better question now.  I voted to reopen.